# Impedance-matched antenna with an extra capacitor

Tags: capacitor, antenna, esp8266, impedance-matching

I'm looking at the a schematic for an ESP8285 module, and I am curious about what they are doing with the antenna. The module is the PSF-B85 (by ITEAD: the version with a chip antenna). The antenna is used for the 2.4GHz WiFi/ISM band.

According to the [ESP8285 datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/0a-esp8285_datasheet_en_v1.0_20160422.pdf) (page 9 of the PDF), the antenna connection pin, LNA, has an output matched to 50 Ohms within the IC. So there aren't any matching topologies necessary for a 50 Ohm antenna.

In the schematic of the PS-B85, a 10pF, 50V capacitor has been placed between the chip antenna and the LNA pin. What is the purpose of this capacitor?
[image: C27, the capacitor in series with the antenna]

I can only guess that this would be a "blocking capacitor", but would it be necessary for proper function? Or is it a small optimization for the antenna?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the antenna is not fully tuned to the right frequency without matching components. In the [datasheet](https://www.johansontechnology.com/datasheets/2450AT18B100/2450AT18B100.pdf) for the antenna they specify a matching circuit themselves.

[image]

Maybe they figured this 10pF cap was enough to satisfy their specifications and get good enough results.

Answer (score 2):

It could be a cheap band pass filter. Self resonant frequency of 10pf is roughly 2.5 GHz. See this for example http://psearch.en.murata.com/capacitor/product/GRM1555C1H100JA01%23.html

It passes the wifi band nicely but attenuates the harmonic frequencies. If there is a problem with the harmonics, this trick could attenuate them a few desibels and make it comply to regulations.